# PREG_MATCH Problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
preg_match("/<img onClick='this\.style\.maxWidth=\"490px\"; this\.style\.maxHeight=\"490px\";
this\.style\.cursor=\"default\";' style='cursor: pointer; display: block; float: left; max-width: 
490px; max-height: 160px;' src='(.)+'><br style='clear: left;'>/",$CONTENT,$MATCHES);
print_r($MATCHES);
```

Why doesn't this get the image source?

Comment: wow. first separate CSS and JS from HTML, then we'll talk about regexp...

Comment: Thanks for not answers my question... btw i figured out that it didn't work because I put (.)+ not (.+) .....

Comment: Thanks for writing such an unclear question...People need to read this you know. BTW I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Can you post HTML source that you are trying to parse? It would be easier to help.
I wrote some general regex, it might be useful for your case. After aplying this regex, you can extract results from group number 1 (results[1]) to get image src. <\s*img[^\>]*[src]\s*=\s*[\"\']{0,1}([^\"\'\>]*)

Comment: I can't believe one of those Regex haters hasn't posted a comment about how parsing HTML with Regex contributes to the rise of Cthulhu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider writing `src='(.+)'` instead of `src='(.)+'`

Answer (score 2):

You can skip a lot of that stuff and just say

```
preg_match("/<img.*?src='([^']*)'/i", $content, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will be the src url

(Before the comments get out of hand: This is based on the original pattern in the question. it doens't match double-quoted attributes, because the original pattern didn't either. And it's not a general solution either. It'll look for 1 well-formed img tag, and that's it)

---

Other than that:

- Inline CSS?!
- Inline event handlers?!
- <strike>*Single quotes* around attributes?!</strike> whoops! Wrong about that one! Apologies

None of that is good!

Comment: That may work for this case, but it's not generally useful/correct regexp pattern.

Comment: @Dor: Please elaborate. I mean, yes, the html is pretty bad to begin with, but what's wrong with the pattern?

Comment: if the subject string contains 2 or more `img` tags, then your old regex (before you edited) could've match the `src` attribute of the latest `img` tag. Now, after you edited the regex, the pattern may match the value of a `src` property when something like `this.src='val'` is written in javascript (perhaps in the OnClick event value)

Comment: Well your pattern matches incorrect Html syntax. For example something like this can be matched with your pattern <img width="150" /> src='/images/prijavise-facebook.gif'

Comment: @Flambino Have you considered that single and double quotes may be used to quote the src?

Comment: @Flambino None necessary. It's an easy fix with an or pipe. `"|'`

Comment: @svlada: True, I simplified it there - i just looked at the original pattern, and used that as a starting point. Judging from that, my pattern should work fine, but no, it's not a completely general solution